# Python's time.sleep() method waits incorrect amount of time

Tags: python, time

I've run into this problem a few times; restarting python seems to work (or ipython). But, for instance, here's one possible output of running the following code:

```
startt = time.time()
for i in range(4):
    time.sleep(1)
    print '%.3f'%(time.time()-startt)
```

I obtain:

```
9.989
10.989
11.990
12.991
```

Why does it wait so long before it begins working? Occasionally, it will start at 10 or even 11 seconds after I run the command.

I'm using Mac OS X (Mavericks), IPython 1.2.1 (with pylab), Python 2.7.5

I'm importing:
os, cv2, time, random, Quartz, LaunchServies, pdb, sys, appscript, and numpy.

Comment: That is rather alarming. What OS? What version of Python?

Comment: Mac OS X (Mavericks), IPython 1.2.1, Python 2.7.5

Comment: How are you running your code? Is it in a script? A function? Are you copying and pasting it in an interactive shell? I can't replicate the large first value, but I do consistently get slightly more than 1 between the rest of the values (which is to be expected)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per the [`time.sleep` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep):

> Suspend execution for the given number of seconds. The argument may be a floating point number to indicate a more precise sleep time. The actual suspension time may be less than that requested because any caught signal will terminate the sleep() following execution of that signal’s catching routine. **Also, the suspension time may be longer than requested by an arbitrary amount because of the scheduling of other activity in the system.**

The actual wait time of `time.sleep` is not guaranteed and depends on how the host system is loaded. If something on your machine gets hold of the resources the Python process may get delayed until resumed.

Still, the delay of seconds is just too high. Are you by any chance trying this in the Python interactive shell? If so, it may interfere, e.g.:

```
>>> import time
>>> startt = time.time()
>>> for i in range(4):
...     time.sleep(1)
...     print '%.3f'%(time.time()-startt)
...
3.147
4.147
5.147
6.147
>>> startt = time.time()
>>> for i in range(4):
...     time.sleep(1)
...     print '%.3f'%(time.time()-startt)
...
4.949
5.949
6.949
7.949
```

Because the `startt = time.time()` gets evaluated before the rest of the code gets written or pasted in and evaluated, which can take seconds.

But it behaves as expected if I wrap it in a method:

```
>>> def test():
...     startt = time.time()
...     for i in range(4):
...         time.sleep(1)
...         print '%.3f'%(time.time()-startt)
...
>>> test()
1.000
2.000
3.000
4.000
```

or put into a script:

```
import time

startt = time.time()
for i in range(4):
    time.sleep(1)
    print '%.3f'%(time.time()-startt)

# $ python test.py
# 1.000
# 2.008
# 3.008
# 4.008
```

In this case the delays should be in order of milliseconds, as can be seen in the latter output. I doubt it could get to seconds.

Comment: Not sure if you can type things directly into the console like this. The time reflects the time you need to write your other lines, after it gets `startt`. You will have to put it in a file and run the file. In my case, there is no lag.

Comment: In your case, you write 3 lines of text in 3-4 seconds. Very impressive.

Comment: @ssm You can type or paste stuff like this into the interactive shell, yes. You know, I was just wondering why it behaves like this till you hit me. I'm overworked ... Thank you :)

Comment: Yeah! I've been using IPython because I was actively developing a script, and using IPython's (glorious) magic function %paste, which inputs formatted text from your clipboard into the console. Despite trying, I've been unable to recreate the problem when running the script itself in python.

Comment: Addendum: It is *not* guaranteed to function as such if I wrap it in a method, if that method is being used in IPython. However, again, executed as a script it appears to run fine, although the script lacks many of the diagnostic features I was using in ipython (namely, rendering images via opencv and plotting figures via matplotlib).