# 10 s delay time for time.sleep in ipython after matplotlib 3.x.x import

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, anaconda, ipython

I realize that time.sleep() calls the OS timer and can vary a little (as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355257/pythons-time-sleep-method-waits-incorrect-amount-of-time) points out), but I am seeing a very large delay time in Ipython. This seems to just happen after I have imported matplotlib.pyplot. Then right after waiting about 30 seconds, it starts to lag. To give a working example, try entering iPython:

```
>>import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# after 30 seconds
>>%time time.sleep(1)                                                        
CPU times: user 5.27 ms, sys: 3.58 ms, total: 8.85 ms
Wall time: 11 s
```

Using slightly longer times in sleep appears to have an additive effect:

```
>>%time time.sleep(3)                                                        
CPU times: user 4.75 ms, sys: 3.7 ms, total: 8.45 ms
Wall time: 13 s
```

Very occasionally the wall time is appropriate, but only about 1/10 of the time. I also tried boxing the sleep in a function as follows:

```
>>def test(): 
     start = time.time() 
     for i in range(4): 
         time.sleep(1) 
         print(f'{time.time() - start}')

>>test()                                                                
11.000279188156128
22.000601053237915
33.000962018966675
44.001291036605835
```

This also occasionally shows smaller time steps, but this is the usual output. I also put the same function in a separate file and used %run script.py in iPython, with the same result. Thus, it happens anytime time.sleep is called.

The only things that seems to work are (a) not importing matplotlib.pyplot

or (b) defining a function based on a simple all-python timer:

```
>>def dosleep(t): 
     start = time.time() 
     while time.time() - start < t: 
         continue

>>%time dosleep(2)                                                      
CPU times: user 1.99 s, sys: 8.4 ms, total: 2 s
Wall time: 2 s
```

The last example seems like a good solution, but I have a decent amount of code that relies on time.sleep() already, and I would like to still use Jupyter with an Ipython kernel. Is there any way to determine what is holding it up, or are there any tips on how to decrease the lag time? I'm just wondering what sort of thing could cause this.

I'm on Mac OS X 10.14.3, running Python 3.6.8 (Anaconda). My Ipython version is 7.3.0. It works the same for iPython 7.4.0. The matplotlib version is 3.0.3. The problem does not occur until the interactive GUI system is interacted (which is immediately at the import for matplotlib 3.x and at the creation of a figure (plt.figure()) with matplotlib 2.x). It occurs when an icon appears in the dock called "Python 3.6".

Comment: Do you have the same problem with an asynchronous sleep, like `asyncio.sleep`? Do you have a minimal working example that we could try to reproduce?

Comment: @cglacet I'm not super familiar with asyncio, but using this [example](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-task.html#example-coroutine-displaying-the-current-date) seems to return similar results. About 11 seconds delay time. A working example is a bit hard because the package I'm using is fairly involved. I was just now able to narrow it down to one package import, however. When I use "import qcodes as qc" (where qcodes is a package found [here](https://qcodes.github.io/Qcodes), and use time.sleep a few times, it happens.

Comment: Correction to the last comment: the problem seems to happen when I import matplotlib.pyplot, and after waiting 30 secs, as I’ve updated in my original question

Answer (score 0):

I realized this time.sleep delay behavior happens only when using the matplotlib backends Qt5Agg and Qt4Agg. This happens whether I use iPython or the regular python console. It doesn't occur when running a file by entering "python filename.py" into the Terminal, though it does hold up files that are run through the iPython or python consoles. When the plotting GUI starts, the time.sleep behavior kicks in after around 30 seconds or so.

I was able to fix the problem by switching the backend to TkAgg, which works similarly and appears to work well in interactive mode. I just made a file called "matplotlibrc" in my base user folder (~) and added the line

```
 backend      : TkAgg
```

to make the default backend TkAgg. This doesn't entirely answer why it happens, but it fixes the problem.